# MinionPro and beamer: figure selection

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts, minionpro

`MinionPro` package options for figure selection don't appear to work under `beamer`. I'd like text figures in text mode (`textosf`) and lining figures in math mode (`mathlf`). In the example below, the numbers in math mode appear as text figures, not lining figures as expected.

I can hook figure selection into various commands/environments to get the desired effect, but this workaround (at least as I've implemented it) is messy. Is there a better solution?

```
\documentclass[serif,professionalfonts]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mathlf,textosf]{MinionPro}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathlf}{T1}{MinionPro-LF}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide title}
  Math mode: $012345$, \(012345\),
  \[012345,\]
  \begin{equation*}
    012345.
  \end{equation*}
  Text mode: 012345.
  Select lining figures: \figureversion{lf}012345, \(\mathlf{012345}\).
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `professionalfont` option. You get lining figures in math mode if you replace

```
\documentclass[serif,professionalfonts]{beamer}
```

by

```
\documentclass[serif,professionalfont]{beamer}
```

(no 's'). Alternatively, you can use the `professionalfonts` font theme by issuing `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` in the preamble. By the way, the class option `serif` is obsolete; you should use `\usefonttheme{serif}` instead.

Comment: So either `\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}` and `\usefonttheme{serif}` or just `\usefonttheme{serif,professionalfonts}`. Clearly I am not reading the documentation closely enough. Thanks for this!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Clearly, it is unfortunate that the class option has a different name than the font theme.